# Lord Jagannath Rath Yatra 2017 all rituals with Date

Tags: vishnu, gods, festivals

Rath Yatra of Lord Jagannath is one of the most viewed car festivals of the world. What are the rituals on this multi-day festival and their dates this year?

Answer (score 1):

Rajendrabhisekha – 04.06.2017

Rukmaniharan Ekadashi – 05.06.2017

Champaka Dwadashi – 06.06.2017

Daitapai Prabesha & Charabandha – 07.06.2017

Chhaturdashi Senapata Lagi – 08.06.2017

Debasnana Purnima – 09.06.2017

Dashami Chaka Bije – 19.06.2017

Khalilagi Ekadashi – 20.06.2017

Rajaprasad Bije (Dwadashi) – 21.06.2017

Ghanalagi – 22.06.2017

Netroutsav & Nabajaubana Darshan – 24.06.2017

Srigundicha – 25.06.2017

Hera Panchami – 29.06.2017

Dakhina Moda – 30.06.2017

Sandhya Darshan – 02.07.2017

Bahuda Yatra – 03.07.2017

Suna Besha – 04.07.2017

Adharapana – 05.07.2017

Neeladribije – 06.07.2017